# Form action and onclick button

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I have a form with an action (note I am using reactstrap):

```
<Form action="/api/exercises" method="post" >
```

Here is the submit button in the form:

```
<Button type="submit" color="primary" onClick={this.addExercise} block>
                Add Exercise
              </Button>
```

I need to be able to run both the onclick function and the form action. I notice that If I have both then it runs the onclick function. If I take out the onclick function then the form action will work. Any ideas on how to be able to run both the form action and the onClick function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. First remove onClick event in Button. And add onSubmit event on Form

```
<Form action="/api/exercises" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} method="post" >


onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // do stuff
  e.target.submit()
}
```

A working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ovqmnjyj2q